# What is the probability that A wins the game?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, problem-solving, dice

A and B are playing a game by alternately rolling a die,with A starting first. Each player’s score is the numbers obtained on his last roll. The game ends when the sum of scores of the two players is 7, and the last player to roll the die wins. What is the probability that A wins the game ?

I did try to solve the question but I just seem to get weird answers and I'm just not able to put my head round it. Thanks for any help :)

Comment: **Hint:** Player $A$ cannot win on the very first throw, but after the first throw, whoever's turn it is has exactly one number they can roll that makes the sum of the final two throws equal seven.

Comment: **Second hint:** Compare this to the game where player $B$ starts instead and to win they just have to be the first player to roll a six on their turn (*their turn only, not the sum of the previous two turns*).

Comment: but then u also need to consider scenarios like 1+1+1+1+1+1+1 (7 times one) , A can still win in 7 throws , 5 trows and 3 throws and I did calculate according to that and umm It's wrong. Do let me know if my approach is wrong.

Comment: "*Each player's score is the numbers obtained on his last roll.*"  I interpret that as meaning the *only* numbers that matter in determining score are only the most recent numbers thrown by each player.  If both players continually roll ones, then at the seventh turn, $A$'s score will still be only two, not seven.  $(1,1,1,1,1,\color{red}{1},\color{blue}{1})$ and it does not yet end the game.  On the other hand an example of a game that does end with a win for $A$ would be $(1,4,2,6,5,1,4,\color{red}{4},\color{blue}{3})$ since $\color{red}{4}+\color{blue}{3}=7$

Comment: The question you seem to have interpreted it as (*which I disagree with*) would be that the players take turns rolling a die and adding *all* of the numbers to happen so far.  The person to roll the die that makes it add to a grand total of seven wins, and the game is a tie if the total goes over seven.  This is a much more tedious problem, effectively needing you to map out all possible ways that the sum of positive integers can equal seven (*thankfully not that many*), noting which result in $A$ winning, and finding the probability of each occurring.

Comment: "The game ends when the sum of scores of the two players is 7, and the last player to roll the die wins" this is what made me think that we're taking the total into account.

Comment: I point you again to the phrase "*Each player's score is the number obtained on his last roll*" which is distinctly different than the phrase "*Each player's score is the total of all numbers obtained on his previous rolls*"

Comment: but the game ends when the sum of their scores is 7 right ? okay oh my god. I see it now. I think I ignored "Last roll". Thank You so much ! Is it coming out to be 5/11 ?

Comment: Assuming my interpretation is the correct one, yes $\frac{5}{11}$ is correct.  Since you had the other interpretation as well, it may be worth going through the effort of solving that problem too for practice (*though it will be considerably more tedious*).

Comment: Yes it was. Thank you so so much ! It isn't even about your interpretation. I read the question wrong. Thanks a lot !